# Why use bind() when I can just copy another method by reference?

Tags: javascript

I was watching a `bind()` tutorial in which they provided the following code as an example of `bind()` - http://jsbin.com/pugogiqupu/1/edit?js,console:

```
function doubleScore() {
  this.score *= 2;
}

function Game() {
  this.score = 1;
  this.double = doubleScore.bind(this);
  this.printScore = function() {
    console.log(this.score);
  }
}

var game = new Game();
game.score = 3;
game.printScore(); // Consoles out: 3
game.double();
game.printScore(); // Consoles out: 6

var game2 = new Game();
game2.score = 4;
game2.printScore(); // Consoles out: 4
game2.double();
game2.printScore(); // Consoles out: 8
```

I noticed that if I omit the `.bind(this)` and simply make a reference to the function without binding it, that it still works.

```
function doubleScore() {
  this.score *= 2;
}

function Game() {
  this.score = 1;
  this.double = doubleScore;
  this.printScore = function() {
    console.log(this.score);
  }
}

var game = new Game();
game.score = 3;
game.printScore(); // Consoles out: 3
game.double();
game.printScore(); // Consoles out: 6

var game2 = new Game();
game2.score = 4;
game2.printScore(); // Consoles out: 4
game2.double();
game2.printScore(); // Consoles out: 8
```

Why is using `bind()` beneficial in this case? What am I missing?

**Edit:** If either method can handle this case, then is there a way to re-write my example that shows how using bind() would be useful?

Comment: It's not beneficial there. You're not missing anything - it is redundant in this particular case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.bind` is only required when you want to call a method *without* using the `object.method()` syntax (which sets the `this` property automatically). In the example you present, there's no benefit to using `.bind`.

A slightly contrived example where you *would* need `.bind`:

```
function doubleScore() {
  this.score *= 2;
}

function tripleScore() {
  this.score *= 3;
}

function Game() {
  this.score = 1;
  this.double = doubleScore.bind(this);
  this.triple = tripleScore.bind(this);
}

var game = new Game();

const multiply = someCondition ? game.double : game.triple;
// Calls the method without context; "this" will only refer
// to "game" because of the binding
multiply();
```

This is most useful when you want to hand `multiply` off to some other function or process that doesn't know about `game`, e.g. an event handler:

```
// Multiply by some factor when the user clicks a button
document.getElementById('multiplyButton')
  .addEventListener("click", multiply);
```

Answer (score 0):

Binding `this` manually is especially interesting when it comes to callbacks, where the context will change:

```js
var X = function() {
  this.a = 1;
}

X.prototype.print = function() {
  setTimeout(function() { console.log(this.a) }, 100);
}

new X().print() // undefined
```

**versus**

```js
var X = function() {
  this.a = 1;
}

X.prototype.print = function() {
  setTimeout(function() { console.log(this.a) }.bind(this), 100);
}

new X().print() // 1
```

In order to be able access the object from the callback, it may make sense to bind the context of the function.